# Using depth first search to find the number of unique routes to a node

Tags: java, algorithm, depth-first-search

I have a directed graph with vertexes ABCDE. Using a depth first search, if I wanted to be able to find the number of unique routes from A-C (for example), how would I go about doing it? Here is my current DFS.

```
private final Map<Character, Node> mNodes;
private final List<Edge> mEdges;
private List<Node> mVisited = new ArrayList<>();
int weight;
int numberOfPaths;

public DepthFirstSearch(Graph graph){
    mNodes = graph.getNodes();
    mEdges = new ArrayList<>(graph.getEdges());
    for(Node node : mNodes.values()){
        node.setVisited(false);
    }
}

public void depthFirstSearch(Node source){

    source.setVisited(true);
    List<Edge> neighbours = source.getNeighbouringEdges(mEdges);
    for(Edge edge : neighbours){
        System.out.println(edge.getFrom().getName()+"-"+edge.getTo().getName());
        if(!edge.getTo().isVisited()){

            mVisited.add(edge.getTo());
            weight += edge.getWeight();
            depthFirstSearch(edge.getTo());

        }
    }
```

Comment: If the graph contains cycles the number of path could be infinite. Maybe your graph happens to be acyclic?

Comment: No cycles in the graph :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the graph is a [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) (i.e., there are no cycles in the graph), you can use [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) and solve your problem in linear time.

The following trivial claim characterizes the number of paths from `u` to `v` in the graph:

*If `u=v` then the number of paths from `u` to `v` is 1. Otherwise, the number of paths from `u` to `v` is the total number of paths from `w` to `v` such that `(u,w)` is an edge in the graph.*

The claim implies a simple recursive algorithm, given by the following pseudo code. Note that the pseudo code bellow doesn't use dynamic programming, but a naive recursion. If you need to solve the problem in linear time you should use [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

```
def count_paths(u,v):
    if u == v: return 1
    count = 0
    for each edge (u,w):
        count += count_paths(w,v)
    return count
```

And here's the code in Java:

```
public int countPaths(Graph graph, Node u, Node v) {
    nodes = graph.getNodes();
    edges = new ArrayList<>(graph.getEdges());
    if (u.equals(v)) return 1;
    int count = 0;
    List<Edge> neighbours = u.getNeighbouringEdges(edges);
    for(Edge edge : neighbours){
        w = edge.getTo();
        count += countPaths(graph, w, v);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: This method doesn't appear to show unique paths. I get the same path twice.

Comment: @spogebob92, can you provide a simple example in which the algorithm over counts?